# How can I enable password-less sudo for the apache2 service?

Tags: apache2, sudo, services

**Problem:** I can't figure out how to enable using the apache2 service with password-less sudo. I can enable this for all commands for the user, but as this seems like a bad idea, I want to only enable certain commands.

**Background:** I'm trying to setup a continuous delivery/deployment system and as part of this, I let Ansible run some commands on the target machines. Some of these commands unfortunately require sudo and I need to suppress the password prompt for these. Ideally all authorization of this process works with registered keys instead of passwords.

**Configs:**
(Machine names have been replaced with placeholder values.)

Machine `target.example.com` running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Apache 2.x

Machine `control.example.com` running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ansible 2.7.8

File `/etc/sudoers.d/ansible` on machine `target.example.com`:

`ansible ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service /usr/sbin/apache2 *`

File `/etc/ansible/hosts`on machine `control.example.com`:

```
[production]
target.example.com
```

File `~/deploy.yml` on machine `control.example.com`:

```
---
- hosts: production
  remote_user: ansible

  tasks:
  - name: stop apache
    shell: service apache2 stop
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
  - name: start apache
    shell: service apache2 start
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
```

**Additional info:**
When running `ansible-playbook ~/deploy.yml` on `control.example.com`, I get an error `sudo: a password is required`. I can reproduce the password prompt when logging in to the target via `ssh ansible@target.example.com` and then running `sudo service apache2 stop` and `sudo service apache2 start`. Therefore I'm hesitantly claiming that the problem is somewhere with the sudo configuration on `target.example.com` and Ansible is just the messenger.

I've tried different configs of `/etc/sudoers.d/ansible`, mostly because I'm not certain at all about the correct syntax and tried all kinds of expressions to see what works. The only working one I found is `ansible ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL`, which I want to avoid due to security concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question was conflating two seperate issues. It seems that [it is not possible](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html) to specifcy arguments or flags for the command specification of a line in a sudoers file. Thus the command specification has to either be generalized to `/usr/sbin/service`, which is again insecure, or it has to be changed to enable `NOPASSWD` on a command that is more restrictive than allowing any service to be run with sudo.

Fortunately in this case I can simply use the `apachectl` service directly to allow fine-grained sudo rights for apache and nothing else. The updated file `/etc/sudoers.d/ansible`:

```
ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/apachectl
```

Note that running the Ansible playbook, updated to use `apachectl` still fails with the error message `sudo: a password is required`, however this appears to be a seperate issue with how I attempt to use Ansible or possibly something else. Regardless, it does not seem relevant to the `sudo` issue of the original question.